# How to set a custom value to _id field while writing json document to Mongo DB using spark

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to load a JSON file containing multiple JSON documents into Mongo DB using spark. All I want is that I would like to create a field _id and set it's value to one of the JSON field value,

Say I have a JSON doc like this,

```
{
  recordId: 123,
  firstName: "abc",
  lastName: "xyz"
}
```

I want to write this into mongo DB by setting _id value = recordId value in the following format,

```
{
  _id: 123,
  recordId: 123,
  firstName: "abc",
  lastName: "xyz"
}
```

I was able to achieve the same using elastic search by setting the following property,

```
option("es.mapping.id", "recordId").
```

For Mongo, I tried it using the following way and it doesn't seem to work

```
       val df = spark.read
                     .format("json")
                     .load(dataFile)

      df = df.withColumn("_id",df["recordId"])

      df.write
        .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
        .option("spark.mongodb.output.uri", URI)
        .mode("append")
        .save()
```

Any help to achieve this will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Doing it this way actually worked,

```
        val df = spark.read
                 .format("json")
                 .load(dataFile)

  df = df.withColumn("_id",df("recordId"))
```